# CSS transition/hover-effect not working in Safari

Tags: html, wordpress, css, woocommerce

I'm currently restyling one of my clients sites (http://citycredits.nl/), and I stumbled upon the following problem:

When you hover the products on the homepage, you should get a fadeIn box with the productname/description.

This works great in Chrome, FireFox and InternetExplorer.
But when I run it in Safari (for Windows) the hover doesn't react. However, when I 'mouseout' of the product, the descriptionblock flashes.

The css code:

```
ul.products a li.product .details  {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);

    width: calc(100% - .9em) !important;
    background: rgba(53, 82, 100, .5) !important;
    top: 33% !important;
    bottom: 33% !important;
    height: calc(34% - .9em);
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em !important;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

ul.products a li.product:hover .details {
    -moz-opacity: 1 !important;
    -khtml-opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
}
```

The HTML code for a product:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product ...">
        <div class="details">
           ... details content here ...
        </div>
    </li>
    <li> ... more listitems ... </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/25/apple_kills_windows_pc_support_in_safari_60 take a look at this article

Comment: The latest Safari for Windows is three years old. Recommend using a newer browser to your users. Of course trying to support older browsers is not actually a bad idea, but you have got to draw the line somewhere. Are you still supporting Opera 12?

Comment: I am using Safari 5.1.7 for Windows, because I don't have an Apple device te test on. Even so, the webkit rules should work, right? Is the anyone on an Apple device, who is willing to test the site? (Just teste on Opera 12 with Browserling.com, and that one worked.) Only Safari keeps bugging.

Comment: Using the newest system and safari the mouseover still is buggy and only shows up while fading out on a `mouse out` event

Comment: I have tried to make your mouseover visible, but I was not able to do it. This is kind of really messed up.

Comment: At least part of your issue is explained in my answer below. And while you definitely did the right thing by trimming away unnecessary classes and markup in your question, it looks like you excised something critical in the process. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in creating useful examples for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that your HTML is invalid, and the HTML on your site is not what you posted in your question. You posted:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product ...">
        <div class="details">
           ... details content here ...
        </div>
    </li>
    <li> ... more listitems ... </li>
</ul>
```

What is actually on your site is:

```
<ul class="products">
  <a href="http://...">
    <li class="...">
      <img ...>
      <noscript>&lt;img.../&gt;</noscript>
      <div class="details...">
           ... details content here ...
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a><li> ... more listitems ... </li></a>...
</ul>
```

The only allowable child elements of a `ul` are `li`, `script` or `template`. If you put your `a` inside the `li` then it works as expected on the latest Mac Safari.

Whether or not this suggest fixes your particular issue, please make sure to post an accurate representation of the code that demonstrates your problem. It will save everybody time and help identify an answer more quickly.